# Rotate landscape to make div full screen (using jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, safari

When changing from portrait to landscape on my iPhone using Safari the following code executes:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
        $("#map").css("position", "absolute");
        $("#map").css("top", "0");
        $("#map").css("left", "0");
        $("#map").width(window.innerWidth);
        $("#map").height(window.innerHeight);
    }
});
```

My issue is that the map div seems to only fill half the screen despite asking it to fill the whole screen? Does anyone know why this might be happening? Been scratching my head for a while on this one, can't seem to find any answers.

Comment: If you are using Jquery Mobile, you can try the orientation change event: jQuery( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) { ... } )

Comment: @Mark I am not using jQuery mobile, but the event handler works, the code executes it just doesn't go full screen in terms of height like I ask it to

Comment: I think this falls into category where window.innerWidth/Height returns portrait values when in landscape mode. I suggest on reading this: http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/

Comment: @zvona It doesn't though because I've tested the values of innerWidth and innerHeight and they're both correct